# Error inflating class Button Android studio

Tags: android, button

I am working on an app in Android Studio, and after adding buttons to MainActivity to move to other activities, despite the fact that the layout shows up properly in the editor, I get the error which will be posted at the end. There are other activities in my project which I did not include, because the error refers to activity_main.xml, but I will include them if they are necessary to solve the problem.

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view_img_main_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/grocery_img_1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_inventory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/view_img_main_menu"
    android:text="@string/btn_my_groceries_text"
    android:theme="@style/BtnTheme" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_shopping_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_inventory"
    android:text="@string/btn_shopping_list_text"
    android:theme="@style/BtnTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnInventory;
private Button btnShopList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnInventory = findViewById(R.id.btn_inventory);
    btnShopList = findViewById(R.id.btn_shopping_list);

    btnInventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent inventoryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inventory.class);
            startActivity(inventoryIntent);
        }
    });

    btnShopList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent shopListIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShoppingList.class);
            startActivity(shopListIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the error I get awhen I try to run the code:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.grocerystatusapplication/com.example.grocerystatusapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.grocerystatusapplication:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #15 in com.example.grocerystatusapplication:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3344)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3488)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Han
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
```

Here is styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorLayoutBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="BtnTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorViewBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewTheme" parent="">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I have tried changing the attributes of the Button that the error refers to (line 15, btn_inventory), but I did not get anywhere. Did not come across this error before and don't really understand what is the problem. What can I change to make it work? After looking through posts about the same error, I did not get an answer to my question, there seemed to be a quite a few reasons this error came up.

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace; that whole section of red lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Button tags change

```
android:theme="@style/BtnTheme"
```

to

```
style="@style/BtnTheme"
```

Comment: Exactly. "android:theme" attributes are only used for manifest and not for layouts.

Comment: I have done the changes everywhere I have used android:theme. Now it starts and the buttons do their job, however they lost the color I have assigned to them. The color I set was a shade of green defined in colors.xml. When I used android:theme, in the layout preview, they showed up properly, now they are just gray with white font color. Do I need to change the attributes in styles.xml?

Comment: I don't recognize buttonColorNormal as an attribute of button. Try to change that to
<item name="android:background">@color/colorViewBackground</item>

Comment: <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorViewBackground</item> ended up doing the trick